# null value in dropdownllist(for)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Last day, i saw that in my razor view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FoodId,null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
// and (just another alternative)
@Html.DropDownList("FoodId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And i'm wondering what's going on with the data in the list, where and when data-filling occurs? and what is the difference between the two lines? and how the dropdown got filled with data (because there is data in the execution of the code)

sorry for my bad english

Update #1

Model:
Food.cs and User.cs

```
public partial class Food
{
    public Food()
    {
        this.User = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
}
//
public partial class User
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> FoodId { get; set; }

    public virtual Food Food { get; set; }
}
```

Controller (only action)

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.FoodId = new SelectList(db.FoodSet, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

Omg thanks i'm now stupid :)

**Answer**: *Got filled with* `ViewBag.FoodId`

Comment: `<select>` might be populated via AJAX call, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing a `null` value to the second argument, it it will *automatically, even without javascript and with a cleared cache* look in the `ViewBag` for a key with the same name as the dropdown, otherwise launch exception.
In my case, `null` was passed and it checked the `ViewBag` and found a key

Comment: new thing for me. I was not aware about that. But as per me it is not a best practice to be follow.

Comment: @JineshJain I know, but it was auto-generated

Comment: @Stickly what bout the first statement ? ``DropDownList`` works the way but is same behaviour happens for ``DropDownListFor``